# How would I create an index for an element that's part of an array in cloudant nosql?

Tags: cloudant, nosql

Let's say there's a Document such as the following

```
{
    _id:1234,
    pages:[
    {"name":"a","content":"a1"},
    {"name":"b","content":"b1"},
    {"name":"c","content":"c1"},
    ]
}
```

How would I create a Primary Index, in order to query "name" as a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a map-reduce view to achieve what you want:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc && doc.pages) {
        doc.pages.forEach(function (row) {
            if (row.name) {
                emit(row.name, 1);
                // or if you want to lookup the content part, use
                // emit(row.name, row.content);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```